# Changing LinqDataSource with Button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a GridView on my asp page. I want to change the LinqDataSource with a button click. it's because i have 2 database views and you have to be able to see one of these to views as you wish. My problems is nothing happens when I try to bind the GridView to any of my LinqDataSource'.

My C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Grid.DataSource = lqds_Grid1;
    this.Grid.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Grid.DataSource == lqds_Grid1)
    {
        this.Grid.DataSource = lqds_Grid2;
        this.Grid.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Grid.DataSource = lqds_Grid1;
        this.Grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

my asp code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddressReporting._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="lqds_Grid1" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="AddressReporting.MobileGateway" EntityTypeName="" 
        OrderBy="AdrID, Country" TableName="BarcodeWithLocation">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="lqds_Grid2" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="AddressReporting.MobileGateway" EntityTypeName="" 
        OrderBy="AdrID, Country" TableName="BarcodeWithLocationSorted">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="217px" Width="268px">
</asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: They are retrieved from the database

Comment: They aren't as you set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`

Comment: I had bind the lqds_Grid1 datasource through the design window and it worked fine. But as i removed it and tried to set it with button click nothing happened. But it gets the data now. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `page_load` method (event) work time page loads so it is not quite right so

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!isPostBack) {
       this.Grid.DataSource = lqds_Grid1;
       this.Grid.DataBind();
   }
}
```

you should check page whether it has postback or not

Comment: it means that if page is loading for the first time then datasource is `lqds_Grid1` else if has post back than Page_load is not changing anything so `lqds_Grid2` must work

Comment: im new at asp, so where do i set this postback property ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you could try to set your datasource to null before giving it the new value and after assigning the new value you can call the refresh method of the datagrid to force it to redraw itself

```
this.Grid.DataSource = null;
this.Grid.DataSource = lqds_Grid1;
this.Grid.DataBind();
this.Grid.DataSource.Refresh();
```